# How to set significance level for scipy.stats test

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, data-science, data-analysis

I'm using `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` and `scipy.stats.wilcoxon` to perform t test and the Wilcoxon test, but I have no idea how can I set the significant level for them. In the official documents, nothing about it is mentioned and it seems like no arguments of these two methods are about it. Does anyone know how to set it?

The official documents:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests also report the p-value to the user. This p-value can be used to test a hypothesis at the significance level of your choice. We **reject** the null hypothesis if the p-value is **less** than the significance level. For example, with a p-value of 0.073 we reject at the significance level of 10% but do not reject at a significance level of 5%.